# Referencing an asset file path from a nestjs script file

Tags: node.js, nestjs, sendgrid

I have a nestjs app, which has a file structure roughly like this:

```
project-folder/
   dist/
   node_modules/
   src/
      auth/
      config/
      scripts/
      ...
      test_assets/
           test_photo.jpg
      sendgrid.tsx
```

I'm just testing something locally, so I'm invoke the function within `sendgrid.tsx` to send an email via a terminal command.

What I'm trying to do is modify my working Sendgrid email function to include an attachment - to test it out, I want it to send an email with test_photo.jpg. So in sendgrid.tsx, I'm doing:

```
async function sendEmailSendgrid (...) {
    const dataToSend = {
        [Parameters about the email, like from, content, etc.]
    }
    
    const testAttachment = {
      filename: 'test_photo.jpg',
      path: "./test_assets/test_photo.jpg", // !! <- This is the question
      cid: 'image_cid',
    };

    dataToSend["attachments"] = [testAttachment]
```

This is returning an error - I suspect it's because the file path isn't correct. What is the correct file path to be using here?